# External drive is extremely slow and freezing when saving files on it

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, gparted

I'm cloning repositories on my 5T external drive. It is extremely slow. It is *not* an SSD, but I feel that something is wrong somewhere.

I created two partitions on it:

- 10k MB (~10 GB): `ext4`
- the rest is `ntfs`

Even when reading or saving a file (using `vim` or any other editor) it takes more than 10 seconds to read/save the content.

I feel that something is weird. Not sure if it's hardware problem (I bought the hard drive two months ago) or I just have to format it again.

After buying it I didn't format it. It was fast enough. I formatted it yesterday (tried to play with `ext4` and `ntfs`) and since then it got super slow and often is freezing (any read/write operation get stuck).

What can I do? I'm using Linux (specifically Ubuntu 15.10, but I don't this is related to distribution).

Should I reformat it using `gparted` in another way? If so, how?

I want to store on this drive lots of git repositories.

Relevant output:

```
$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for ionicabizau: 

/dev/sdb:
 Timing cached reads:   11350 MB in  2.00 seconds = 5677.48 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  22 MB in  3.16 seconds =   6.96 MB/sec

$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb1 
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-4.2.0-27-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Seagate
Product:              Expansion Desk
Revision:             0909
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        5.000.981.077.504 bytes [5,00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LB provisioning type: unreported, LBPME=0, LBPRZ=0
Logical Unit id:      0x3e413845454a5245
Serial number:        NA8EEJRE
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Sun Feb 14 10:21:01 2016 EET
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
```

Comment: What brand & model of drive is it?  How is it connected to the computer?  What are the types and sizes of the files you are trying to save that are showing it being "slow and often freezing"?

Comment: Maybe it spinned down / went to sleep? Does the >10s delay always occur even when you contiguously read/save multiple files?

Comment: @MekkiMacAulay It freezes even when saving/creating (it doesn't matter) a file containing `abc` (`vim foo`, `i`, `abc`, `<esc>`, `:x`). The model is *HDD extern Seagate Expansion 5TB, 3.5", USB 3.0*,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unlikely to be a partitioning thing - but  7MB / second is very slow, and something is wrong - even for USB2 I'd expect a speed of > 30 MB/sec

Have you tried it in different ports - I suspect this might be a USB device driver issue - if you get lucky you may have some USB2 and some USB3 ports which behave differently - try each - also try going through a USB hub and directly if you can.

It is remotely possible that the drive is failing - see if you can get smartctl stats from it with smartctl -i /dev/sdX and also try doing a short and long S.M.A.R.T test if its compatible with your device.

Comment: Another thing to try might be to copy (part of) the 10 gig partition to your internal drive  using something like gnu ddrescue which will tell you both the speed for reads (ignoring filesystem as it works at the block level) and if there are difficulties reading that part of the disk.

Comment: I added the `smartctl` output.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *doing a short and long S.M.A.R.T test*—but `S.M.A.R.T` is not available.

Comment: Running `sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb` gives me now ` Timing buffered disk reads:  12 MB in  3.13 seconds =   3.83 MB/sec`. I tried all my machine ports.

Comment: Try the disk in another machine.  If it still gives those kinds of speeds its stuffed.  If it doesn't, look at the USB drivers/modules for your system.

Comment: We tried it on a Windows machine. There it's not working at all. The whole system freezes while the hard drive is plugged in. Looks like a hardware issue to me. Hope the guys from warranty will solve my issue. :) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Confirming it was a hardware problem. They replaced my hard disk and now it's working perfectly (~130MB/sec).